# Dojo.require() trying to load cross domain resource

Tags: dojo

I am very new to Dojo and I am having an issue with dojo.require(). I am using the Dojo version that is hosted in the cloud. I would like to load my own modules with dojo.require(), but this doesn't really seem to work. I have set the basUrl, but whenever I try to load the module I get an error about accessing a cross domain resource (and it takes some time before this error actually occurs). The file it is trying to load is the module I requested. When I am debugging I can just ignore this error, and my module is still loaded correctly. But I am unable to find out why exactly Dojo is trying to load something cross domain...

This is how the header of my HTML file looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: true,
        baseUrl: '../../' 
    };
</script>    

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("client.apps.customers.overview");

    dojo.ready(function () {
        overview.open();
    });
</script>
```

"client.apps.customers.overview" is my own module I am trying to load. This how the start of the overview.js file looks like:

```
dojo.provide("overview");

dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
```

Comment: The cross-domain modules are those "in the cloud", not your own. Can you post your head section here to see how you configure dojo and how you make your requires ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, the file overview.js needs to be placed in client/apps/customers/ (relative to your baseUrl), and the dojo.provide call must be given both the full namespace and the class. In your case:

```
dojo.provide("client.apps.customers.overview");
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work. It seems that Dojo is actually trying to load "client.apps.customers.overview" as a cross domain resource.

Comment: @svb: Strange. Just to check, can you try using djConfig instead of dojoConfig?

Comment: @svb Or if it's more convenient, run `alert(dojo.config.baseUrl);` in the firebug console after your application has loaded. The reason I'm suggesting this is that this thread hints at a possible bug with the djConfig/dojoConfig migration: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojoConfig-scopeMap-how-td3215933.html

Comment: @svb Hmm, I'm not able to reproduce it here. Printing dojo.config.baseUrl in the console results in "../../" right?

Comment: I found the problem. Your original solution worked fine, but I forgot to change the references in my code from "overview" to "client.apps.customers.overview". Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I spoke to soon. It just seems to work fine in Firefox. In other browsers (Opera & Internet Explorer) it doesn't work.

Comment: Very odd. Is the error in Opera and IE still a "Failed to load ... last tried ..." error (where it looks for your module at googleapis) or is it something else? Make sure it's not just the browser cache playing tricks with you too!

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was a caching problem. The caching seems to be a bit aggressive, so I will have to do something about this :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Frode's suggestion of matching the require and provide declarations, I think you need to add an extra configuration to tell dojo where to find the "client" namespace:

```
dojoConfig = {
    /*...*/,
    modulePaths: {
        client: 'path_to_the_client_folder'
    }
};
```

You can check if this is reason for the error by looking on the Firebug/Chrome console at what resource you are currently trying to fetch when you do the require call. I believe it may be searching for the "client" module in the default location of `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/client`, (next to dojo, dijit and dojox) but your module would definitelly be somewhere else.